# VideoJS+HTML5 Autoplay FAIL for Android 2.3+ and IOS 4+

Tags: html, video.js

My VideoJS and HTML5 project is targeting more recent web browsers ( newer versions of FireFox and Chrome ) as well as mobile browsers ( Android2.3+ and IOS4+ ).

I want all my videos to autoplay after they are "ready". I've tried doing this a couple ways ( mentioned in methods below ) but noticed that the autoplay only really works in FireFox and Chrome -- meaning the mobile browsers just sit and spin.

I haven't gotten as far as debugging the mobile browsers in their native emulators cause i wanted to see if someone here had previous advice on how to trouble shoot this.

Thanks

**Method 1**

Add the **`autoplay="true"`** attribute to the **`<video>`** tag:

```
<video id="my_videoplayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
autoplay="true" preload="auto" width="425" height="225" poster="/img/Logo.png"
data-setup="{}">
    {% if is_help_video %}
    <source src="{{rackspace_cdn_url}}{{video_id}}" type="{{video_type}}">
    {% else %}
    <source src="{{rackspace_cdn_url}}{{video_id}}" type="{{video_type}}">
    {% endif %}
</video>
```

**Method 2**

Remove **`autoplay="true"`** attribute from **`<video>`** tag and try it through the VideoJS API on "ready" callback:

```
_V_('my_videoplayer').ready(function(){  

    MIMIC.video_player = this;

    this.addEvent( "ended", function(){

        {% if not is_help_video %}
            show_transition( true );
        {% endif %}

    });

    /*
    **
    **  try autoplay
    **
    */
    this.play();

});
```

Comment: This is strange because I've been using autoplay with jPlayer (which has a ton of other problems, though) and it works on Android too. So there must be a way to make it work...

Comment: The attribute 'autoplay="true"' should just be 'autoplay' as for when an attribute is present it's set to 'true' you only assign when something is different than 'true'

Answer (score 1):

iOS browsers don't support playback before any human interaction. Autoplay just does not work, and there has to be a touch/click event before initiating playback via the API. Android browsers now follow that behaviour.

Comment: Is there a way to add a conditional to the code so that a button appears for mobile browsers but it autoplays on desktop browsers?